# Docker rm does not remove my container if the physical machine dies

Tags: bash, security, docker

I have some containers that hold sensitive information in its file system during their existence. I create those containers using a line such as:

```
docker run -it --rm someImage bash
```

Whenever I exit bash my container disappears along with all the sensitive files, which is precisely what I wanted. If I use a Docker container then I do not need to remember to delete those files. This solution is also better than putting files in /tmp since all files are removed right after I stopped using them.

The problem is when my physical machine dies for some reason. For instance, if I trip on the power cable. When this happens, my container goes to the stopped state and someone else can restart the container using

```
docker start myContainerId
```

Is there any way to improve the way I create my container to achieve what I want? One way to go would be to put something on the host machine's SystemV to erase those containers at startup, but I wonder if Docker does not have a better way to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

Just use *docker rm*

`docker rm <containerid>`

(it only works on stopped containers)

Comment: This is precisely what I do not want to do. Not having to worry about calling docker rm is what the --rm argument is all about.